# Как правильно сделать множественный биндинг к свойству кнопки IsEnabled?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

Есть форма с несколькими полями. Проверка правильности ввода происходит на уровне данных (в `Entity Framework`) `ValidatesOnDataErrors=True`. Как правильно будет привязать свойство кнопки `IsEnabled` к правильности заполнения всех полей?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Привязаться можно к `Validation.HasError == false`

Вообще, проверка должна быть на уровне `View-Model`, к которому интерфейс и привязывается, а про уровень данных представлению ничего знать не надо.

В самом [`MSDN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.validatesondataerrors.aspx) вполне понятный пример на эту тему.

Comment: Может быть просто не правильно выразился. Наверно именно в модели происходит валидация. "Привязаться можно к Validation.HasError == false" я думал об этом. Вопрос в том, как привязаться ко многим полям Validation.HasError.

Comment: У Вас несколько моделей, и на каждой из них реализован IDataErrorInfo?

В этом случае обычный множественный биндинг используйте ([MSDN][1]).

  [1]: http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.data.multibinding.aspx

Comment: Еще добавлю, что в разметке надо выражение надо указывать в скобках (много времени потерял на этом):

    <Button x:Name="AcceptButton" Width="70" Height="25" Margin="3" Click="AcceptButton_Click">
                <Image Source="/GUI;component/Images/tick.png" Height="16" />
                <Button.IsEnabled>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource multiConverter}">
                        <Binding ElementName="tbName" Path="(Validation.HasError)"/>
                        
                    </MultiBinding>
                </Button.IsEnabled>
            </Button>